# ASP.NET Attribute Routing - Url.Action not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

This code works fine:

```
[RouteArea("Main", AreaPrefix = "Hello")]
[RoutePrefix("{orgCode}")]
public class ResponseController : BaseController {
  [Route("Save/{formCode}/{responseId}")]
  public ActionResult Save(string formCode, int responseId, string questionCode){}
}
```

and `Url.Action("Save", "Response")` produces, for example, `/Hello/org123/Save/form/123`

However, if the Route attribute is changed and another segment added:

```
  [Route("Save/{formCode}/{responseId}/{questionCode}")]
```

then `Url.Action("Save", "Response")` produces an empty string.

Is there a limit to how many sections can be defined in the route?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a limit to how many sections can be defined in the route?

No.

But MVC only can build URLs using route values that it knows about. This can be a combination of route values that are **passed** to the `Url.Action()` method and values that are in the current request (usually passed through the current URL).

When the framework tries to determine which route to use, it selects the *first route* that matches *all of the route values* (controller, action, and anything else) and matches all of the (optional) constraints.

The route *will not match* if all of the conditions below are true for any of the parameters:

1. Have no defaults
2. Are not marked `UrlParameter.Optional` (NOTE: Optional parameters may not have any non-optional parameters to the right of them)
3. Are not present in the current request
4. Are not explicitly passed as route values to `Url.Action()` (or other method that calls `UrlHelper` to generate a URL)
5. Have constraint rules that do not match

In short, a route only matches if all of the required parameters are provided and constraints are satisfied.

So, apparently there is no `questionCode` in the current context, and since it is required to build the URL, you get an empty string. Most likely you need to pass it explicitly.

```
Url.Action("Save", "Response", new { questionCode = "123" })
```

You should also be careful to always explicitly pass other parameters if there may be cases where they are not present in the URL.